# html remember the selected option from drop down navigate to selected option

Tags: javascript, html

hey i am working on a website that has multi language support in HTML I have different pages for each and every functionality Now say if the user select a particular language like say Chinese and is on the HOME page and wants to navigate to CONTACTUS page,but when the CONTACTUS  page loads it load in ENGLISH which is a default language which is wrong if the user has selected Chinese the CHINESE's pages should only be loaded how can i go about

Comment: You will need to provide some more details on how your localization works...

Answer (score 0):

Save the Selection in SESSION['LanguageName'] and on different pages, retrieve the value in SESSION['LanguageName'] and load the dropdown and page accordingly.

Comment: HEy how can i store the selected value/name of the dropdown in a session and how can use it on to a different page its HTML sorry i am really new to it

Answer (score 0):

An option would be using SESSION variables to remember the selection and then when the user opens a new page, check that variable and load the corresponding language.

Another option is to use a URL parameter to identify the language, like ?lang=ES. This is better for search engines indexing. Again, when the user enters on a page, check that variable and load the corresponding language. All links on the page should have this parameter too, to keep the language.

Comment: HEy how can i store the selected value/name of the dropdown in a session and how can use it on to a different page its HTML sorry i am really new to it